# Symfony -> How to make created and modified fields dynamic with Doctrine?

Tags: date, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2 (or Symfony3) and I can't find how to set doctrine (with annotations config) to automatically save it in my entities when 'created' or 'modified' fields.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here my solution after this time ...

You just need to put this directly into your entity class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class MyEntity {

   //....

    public function __construct() {
        // we set up "created"+"modified"
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
        if ($this->getModified() == null) {
            $this->setModified(new \DateTime());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function updateModifiedDatetime() {
        // update the modified time
        $this->setModified(new \DateTime());
    }

    //....    
}
```

It works well actually

Comment: Don't forget you have to provide `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` on the Entity when using lifecycle callbacks. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-haslifecyclecallbacks

Comment: In your entity: Create properties along with setters and getters for created & modified. Set their data type to datetime. Then use the code above... it's perfect (without the need to load - and spend a lot of time configuring - more stuff. Very nice Solution!)

Comment: This is the most easiest way to manage date object that I found so far :)

Comment: I don't think you need the `setModifed()` call in the constructor if you have the `PrePersist()`

Comment: @tobymackenzie: in my case without that code in the contructor, loading fixtures didn't work because of null on Modified.

Comment: This code to me on update also update and `created` column. I test it in my bundle now

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't it be the `created` property that is inside the `if` statement? Surely `created` should only be set once?

Answer (score 26):

You can use [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle). This describes in [symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html). It contains [Timestampable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) behavior.

```
/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updated;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updatedTimestamps()
{
    $this->setModifiedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

    if($this->getCreatedAt() == null)
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
    }
}
```

You dont need to call in `__constructor` anything. Just create `getter` and `setter` properties `created`, `modified` and that is all.

If you set first `setCreated()` on every update you will update also `created` colum. So put first `setModifedAt()`

Comment: Seems that `new \DateTime()` is shorter version of `new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`.

Comment: @zored You can use `DateTime('now')` which makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Two more examples (if you're using Yaml or Xml mapping):

```
Entity\Product:
  type: entity
  table: products
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 32
    created_at:
      type: date
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    updated_at:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: update
```

And xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping">

    <entity name="Mapping\Fixture\Xml\Timestampable" table="timestampables">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <field name="created_at" type="datetime">
            <gedmo:timestampable on="create"/>
        </field>
        <field name="updated_at" type="datetime">
            <gedmo:timestampable on="update"/>
        </field>
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: This method requires the gedmo/doctrine-extensions third-party package: https://packagist.org/packages/gedmo/doctrine-extensions

Answer (score 3):

The other answers suggest using `if` statements (which means repeating your property names) and having property-setting logic in the constructor that might never be used.

Alternatively, you could have `onAdd` and `onUpdate` methods that are called when needed:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function onAdd()
{
    $this->setAdded(new DateTime('now'));
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onUpdate()
{
    $this->setUpdated(new DateTime('now'));
}
```